# how to access state variable in componentDidMount in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of null"
the above error message is what i get....
following is my code

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    desc: '',
  }
}

componentDidMount = () => {
  var ref = fire.database().ref("Employers/Employer1");
  ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

    this.setState({
      desc: snapshot.val()
    })
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log(this.state.desc);
    console.log(snapshot.val().Description);
    console.log('====================================');
  });

  // snapshot.val() is the dictionary with all your keys/values from the '/store' path


}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because of `this` behavior in javascript. There are two ways to solve it. First to use arrow function, change third line to

```
ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", (snapshot) => {
```

other way is to assign value of this to another variable and use state by using that variable. forexample

```
const self = this;
ref.orderByKey().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

    this.setState({ desc: snapshot.val() })
    console.log('====================================');
    console.log(self.state.desc);
    console.log(snapshot.val().Description);
    console.log('====================================');
});
```

For understanding `this` you can read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer please accept and vote answer

Answer (score 2):

**componentDidMount** is a life cycle hook, it need not be an arrow function.

**change**

```
componentDidMount = () => {
}
```

**To**

```
componentDidMount(){
}
```